# Spark structured streaming performance regression in latency times reading/writing to kafka since 3.0.2

Tags: performance, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming, latency

During a migration from spark 2.4.4 to spark 3.4.0 I have noticed slower latency times in spark structured streaming when reading and writing to kafka. I have tested using both CONTINUOUS and MICROBATCH.

In simple read and write to kafka using CONTINUOUS mode in spark 2.4.4 I usually see latency times of ~5ms in our appllication.
When moving to spark 3.4.0 this increased to ~15ms.

I stripped it back to a very simple test where I send 2 data fields in csv format to a kafka topic using a simple producer. Then I have a simple consumer which reads from the input topic and writes to an output topic. The 2 fields are an ID and an amount value.
I read from both topics and retrieve the kafka timestamp value for all rows. I then subtract the input timestamp from the output timestamp to get the latency.
To keep things as simple as possible I am using 1 kafka partition and I am using local[1] as the spark master.

| Version | latency (ms) | Trigger |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2.4.4 | 3.25 | CONTINUOUS |
| 3.4.0 | 7.23 | CONTINUOUS |
| 2.4.4 | 640 | MICROBATCH |
| 3.4.0 | 693 | MICROBATCH |

I have tried all versions of spark 3.x and I believe this issue was introduced in 3.0.2.
I also tried different versions of spark 2.4.x and I see the same behaviour when going from 2.4.7 to 2.4.8.

In the simple test I only use a few jars. One of these is spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12
When running on spark 3.0.2 using the 3.0.2 version of this jar I see the slower times.
When I run again on spark 3.0.2 and use the 3.0.1 version of this jar I see the faster times.

The same thing happens between 2.4.7 version and the 2.4.8 version. The 2.4.8 version has the slower times.

Has anyone else observed a slow down in latency in structured streaming when reading from kafka ?

Are there any settings I need to change when moving to these versions ?